# How to reverse first and last character of the the string?

Tags: c#

What does the following code mean?

```
rstr.Substring(rstr.Length - 1) + 
rstr.Substring(1, rstr.Length - 2) + 
rstr.Substring(0,1);
```

Comment: What exactly want? How to replace first with last char or explain what does this part of code??

Comment: [“Can someone help?” is not a question we can answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence just replaces the first character with the last character in the string rstr.

```
rstr.Substring(rstr.Length - 1); //extrcts the last character of the string
rstr.Substring(1, rstr.Length - 2); //extracts all the characters except the first and the last
rstr.Substring(0,1); //extracts the first character.
```

Ex. if rstr = testing, then the output would be gestint.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `StringBuilder` class. Then you can perform a usual swap of any two elements.

```
var str = "Hello World";
var s = new StringBuilder();
s.Append(str);

var tmp = s[0];
s[0] = s[s.Length - 1];
s[s.Length - 1] = tmp;

str = s.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This just answers the question in the title.

Comment: A little explanation would be useful. Not just writing the code